# Norm of matrix and its maximum eigenvalue

Tags: linear-algebra, ordinary-differential-equations, dynamical-systems

I've seen in some inequalities in the theory of ODEs that $\lVert Q \lVert \le \lambda_{max}(Q)$. What theorem from Linear Algebra is relevant here?

Comment: Depends a bit on what $\|Q\|$ means. There are many norms one can put on a matrix.

Comment: I'm not sure, unfortunately. Is there a norm to which this is applicable?

Comment: There are probably lots of norms for which the inequality holds, but you want to know which theorem from Linear Algebra is applicable, and that could depend on which norm you have in mind. So go back to the place(s) where you have seen that inequality, and find out what norm is being used.

Comment: This doesn't sound right. The eigenvalues of an arbitrary matrix are not necessarily real. You cannot speak of their maximum in general. Even if they are real, they aren't necessarily nonnegative. Perhaps your $Q$ is positive semidefinite?

Comment: Any progress, @sequence?

Comment: @GerryMyerson: It's a 2-norm of a matrix. I.e., $\lVert \cdot \lVert_2$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I wonder whether the inequality isn't backward.

$\|A\|_2$ is usually defined as the supremum, over all unit vectors $x$, of $\|Ax\|_2$.

Let $\lambda$ be the largest eigenvalue of $A$ (in modulus), and let $v$ be a corresponding unit eigenvector. Then $$\|A\|_2\ge\|Av\|_2=\|\lambda v\|_2=|\lambda|\|v\|_2=|\lambda|$$

Comment: If $v$ is a unit eigenvector corresponding to any $\lambda$, not necessarily $\lvert \lambda \lvert_{max}$, then $\lVert A \lVert_2 \ge \lVert Av \lVert_2 = \lVert \lambda v \lVert_2 = \lvert \lambda \lvert \lVert v \lVert_2 = \lvert \lambda \lvert$. Correct? Then the norm doesn't need to be related to $\lvert\lambda\lvert_{max}$...

Comment: It is correct that the norm exceeds $|\lambda|$ for all eigenvalues $\lambda$. But that is implied by saying that it exceeds the biggest one.

Comment: Do you think this inequality is valid? $$-\|x\|^2+2x^TQg(x)\\ \leq -\|x\|^2+2\lambda_{\max}(Q)\|x\|\|g(x)\|$$ @GerryMyerson

Comment: I don't know. Why don't you post it as another question? You could also accept my answer, if you found it helpful.

Comment: The main idea of my question is to understand if this inequality is valid. If $Q$ is positive definite, then does it have a different property with respect to its norm and the maximum eigenvalue, such as being equal to the modulus of its greatest eigenvalue?

Comment: WHY DON'T YOU POST IT AS ANOTHER QUESTION?

Comment: There's a limit on how many questions I can ask per period.

Comment: And there's a reason for that. Be more selective in what you ask. Think questions through before you ask them, you might not need to ask so many. Familiarize yourself with the efficient use of internet search engines. If you're at a university, seek out math faculty, and put your questions to them.

Comment: I'll look that up, but I couldn't get much info on the 2-norm from the Wikipedia article.

Comment: There's a lot more to the internet than Wikipedia. Not to mention, there are libraries.

Comment: There is, but often it saves a lot of time to ask a question.

Comment: More precisely, it saves *you* a lot of time.

Comment: Yes, but then there'll be something which I'll want to contribute to others. And those people who contribute here do it for a reason. So everyone will save time for everyone.

Comment: There's nothing to prevent you from posting here something you learn somewhere else. I do it all the time.

Comment: That's right, that's what I mean.

Comment: The inequality $|\lambda|\leq \|A\|$ is true for any *matrix* norm, not specific for $\|\cdot\|_2$.

Answer (score 3):

The equation is backwards, but there is a more general result that is applicable. This result can be found in textbooks such as Theorem 5.6.9 in   *Matrix Analysis* (2012) by Horn and Johnsson:

> Let $\|Q\|$ denote a matrix norm of the matrix $Q$. Let  $\lambda$ be
> an eigenvalue of $Q$. Let $\rho(Q)$ be the spectral norm of $Q$, which
> is the absolute value of the largest eigenvalue:  $\rho(Q) \triangleq |\lambda_{max}(Q)|$.
>
> $$|\lambda| \leq \rho(Q) \leq \|Q\| $$
>
> and if $Q$ is invertible, then  $$\rho(Q) \geq |\lambda| \geq 1/ \|Q\| $$

*Remark*: If $\lambda_{max}(Q)$ is a nonnegative real value, then $\lambda_{max}(Q)=\rho(Q)$, and $ \lambda_{max}(Q) \leq \|Q\|$. Example of such occasions is if $Q$ is positive semidefinite or if $Q$ is a irreducible nonnegative (see Perron-Frobenius theorem).

Comment: Can you please clarify how does it follow from this example that $\rho(Q) \le \|Q\|$?

Comment: @sequence I rewrote the answer to be clearer. better like this?

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the Jordan Normal Form of the matrix to show that all of the eigenvalues are less than the norm of the matrix.