# If $\lambda_{max}$ is the largest eigenvalue of $A$, why is it that $\| Ax \|_2 \leq \| \lambda_{max} x \|_2$ for any vector $x$?

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, linear-transformations

Let $A$ be a square matrix. Let its largest eigenvalue be $\lambda_{max}$. Consider any vector $x$.

It was mentioned in this comment https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3216089/1125279 that $ \| Ax \|_2 \leq \| \lambda_{max} x \|_2 $.

**Why is this true? Any pointers to the name of this theorem?**

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1684898/norm-of-matrix-and-its-maximum-eigenvalue

Comment: Notice: this is true only for normal matrices, since $\|A\| = |\lambda_{max}|$

Comment: @AJL This is only true for **normal** matrices

Comment: For a general matrix $A$, what you *can* say is that $\lVert Ax \rVert_2 \le \sqrt{\lambda_{max}} \lVert x \rVert_2$ where $\lambda_{max}$ is the largest eigenvalue of $A^T A$.  (This is even true for non-square matrices $A$.)

Answer (score 1):

This is not true for all matrices. Let

$$A = \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 1 \\ 0 & 1 \\ \end{pmatrix},$$ and then $$x =(1,1)^{\top}.$$ The largest eigenvalue $\lambda_{\text{max}}$ of $A$ is $\lambda_{\text{max}}=1$, yet, $Ax = (2,1)^{\top}$, giving $||Ax||_2 = \sqrt{5} > \sqrt{2}$ $= ||x||_2 = \lambda_{\text{max}}||x||_2$.